# Can I write an Iterator that mutates itself and then yields a reference into itself?

Tags: rust

I ran into a problem that simplifies into the following:

```
struct MyIter {
    vec: Vec<i8>,
}

fn fill_with_useful_data(v: &mut Vec<i8>) {
    /* ... */
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MyIter {
    type Item = &'a [i8];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a [i8]> {
        fill_with_useful_data(&mut self.vec);

        Some(&self.vec)
    }
}

fn main() {
    for slice in (MyIter { vec: Vec::new() }) {
        println!("{}", slice);
    }
}
```

This generates the error:

```
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/main.rs:9:6
  |
9 | impl<'a> Iterator for MyIter {
  |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter
```

The idea is that the iterator does a bunch of work that reflects in its fields and at each step, it yields a reference into itself to the calling code. In this case I could model it as yielding a copy of the state instead of the reference, but let's pretend that's not possible or just inconveniently expensive.

Intuitively this shouldn't be a problem because the borrow checker can ensure that `.next()` isn't called again while the yielded reference can still be used to inspect the iterator's state, but the `Iterator` trait doesn't seem to provide for that sort of thing directly. Even with some permutations like only holding on to a reference to the vector in the iterator itself or making the iterator a reference or something to get the lifetimes baked into the type earlier on, I can't get anything past the borrow checker.

I read the "[Iterators yielding mutable references](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2013/10/24/iterators-yielding-mutable-references/)" blogpost but I'm not sure if/how it applies to my problem that doesn't involve mutable references.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not possible. If it were allowed one could call `next` again and thus modify data that is also visible via `&` or even invalidate the reference entirely. This is because there is no connection between the `self` object itself and the returned reference: there is no explicit lifetime linking them.

For the compiler to reason about this and allow returning a reference into `self` next needs a signature like

```
fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a [i8]>
```

However, this differs from the signature of the trait which is not allowed as generic code that just takes an `T: Iterator<...>` cannot tell that there are different requirements on the use of the return value for some `T`; all have to be handled identically.

The `Iterator` trait is designed for return values that are independent of the iterator object, which is necessary for iterator adaptors like `.collect` to be correct and safe. This is more restrictive than necessary for many uses (e.g. a transient use inside a `for` loop) but it is just how it is at the moment. I don't think we have the tools for generalising this trait/the for loop properly now (specifically, I think we need associated types with higher rank lifetimes), but maybe in the future.

Comment: All right, I just stopped implementing `Iterator` and made my own for-loop with a macro. I didn't think of how `.collect()` wouldn't work out.

Comment: This is also nice for traversals where you can't use the `for` loop: `while let Some(element) = iter.next() { ...`

Comment: For future reference, this type of iterator (`fn next(&'a self)`) is often referred to as a *streaming iterator*. Some samples of discussions [1](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/returning-borrowed-values-from-an-iterator/1096), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2t1rxx/more_general_iterator_trait/), and a [crate that implements a form of it](https://github.com/sfackler/streaming-iterator).