# Simple as possible example of returning a mutable reference from your own iterator

Tags: reference, iterator, rust, mutable, lifetime

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730586/returning-mutable-references-from-an-iterator) is related, however it moreso covers the reason *why* the compiler cannot infer a safe lifetime when returning a mutable reference from `Iterator::next`, which I think I understand.

My question is:

What are the specific steps you can take when designing your *own* iterator so that it can produce mutable references? Ultimately, I'm hoping for a concise-as-possible, step-by-step, commented example of both an `Iterator` and its `next` implementation that I (and anyone) can go to as a clear reference when they run into this situation. `unsafe` examples are fine, I imagine they are probably necessary!

NOTE: I understand that [`MutItems`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-linux/build/src/libcore/slice.rs.html#1152-1157) is normally the recommended example, however its implementation can be difficult to follow as there isn't any documentation on 1. How the markers work in that situation and 2. What the `iterator!` macro expands to and how it works. If you use `MutItems` as your example could you please clarify these things?

Comment: The `iterator` macro is just a little earlier in the file: http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-linux/build/src/libcore/slice.rs.html#1042-1105

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a way of having a mutable iterator over a hypothetical `Point` struct. I find it *very* useful to annotate every `unsafe` block in a similar fashion, since I'm only shooting myself in the foot if I get it wrong!

The Rust compiler does not know that you will get a different mutable reference every time you advance the iterator. This `unsafe` block is safe because the programmer guarantees that this iterator can *never* return the same mutable reference twice, or allow any other way to get to the same address.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: u8,
    y: u8,
    z: u8,
}

impl Point {
    fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> IterMut {
        IterMut {
            point: self,
            idx: 0,
        }
    }
}

struct IterMut<'a> {
    point: &'a mut Point,
    idx: u8,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for IterMut<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut u8;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut u8> {
        let retval = match self.idx {
            0 => &mut self.point.x,
            1 => &mut self.point.y,
            2 => &mut self.point.z,
            _ => return None,
        };

        self.idx += 1;

        // I copied this code from Stack Overflow without paying attention to
        // the prose which described why this code is actually safe.
        unsafe { Some(&mut *(retval as *mut u8)) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut p1 = Point { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 };

    for x in p1.iter_mut() {
        *x += 1;
    }

    println!("{:?}", p1);
}
```

See also

- [How can I create my own data structure with an iterator that returns mutable references?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730586)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing exactly this in my own use-case. For anyone unsure of what `transmute` does, here's the summary of its behaviour [from the docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html), "Unsafely transforms a value of one type into a value of another type." In this situation transmute infers the correct return type while assuring the borrow checker that the mutable borrow is safe.