# Can't use mutable slice where immutable slice is fine

Tags: rust

I'd like to create a struct that holds a slice, and can return references to items in that slice. So far, I've been able to do this:

```
pub struct Stride<'a> {
    items: &'a [f32],
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Stride<'a> {
    type Item = &'a f32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a f32> {
        Some(&self.items[0])
    }
}
```

However, when I change the slice to be a mutable slice:

```
pub struct Stride<'a> {
    items: &'a mut [f32],
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Stride<'a> {
    type Item = &'a f32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a f32> {
        Some(&self.items[0])
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/lib.rs:8:15
  |
8 |         Some(&self.items[0])
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 7:5...
 --> src/lib.rs:7:5
  |
7 | /     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a f32> {
8 | |         Some(&self.items[0])
9 | |     }
  | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
 --> src/lib.rs:8:15
  |
8 |         Some(&self.items[0])
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 5:6...
 --> src/lib.rs:5:6
  |
5 | impl<'a> Iterator for Stride<'a> {
  |      ^^
  = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
          expected std::option::Option<&'a f32>
             found std::option::Option<&f32>
```

Why can't I hold this mutable slice and return references to the elements in that slice? I would like to go even further: returning mutable references to elements in this slice. Is this even possible?

Comment: I assume that you are asking this to explore how it would be implemented. If you wanted to do this in The Real World, you can just use [`iter_mut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceExt.html#tymethod.iter_mut) from the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, what you want to do is to create an iterator of mutable references. That has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25748645/155423), with at least one [example of how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27118398/155423).

The summary is that Rust cannot tell that you are not returning the *same* mutable reference more than once. If you did so, then you would have *aliasing*, which breaks Rust's rules. As an aside, your iterator as shown **is unsafe** because it will always return the first item! As a human smarter than Rust, you have to manually verify that you aren't breaking the safety rules and then use `unsafe` code to ignore the warnings. Something like `mem::transmute` is often used.