# Lifetime parameter problem in custom iterator over mutable references

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I'd like to implement a custom Iterator like below, but cannot solve reference problem.

```
use itertools::Product;
use std::ops::Range;
struct Iter2DMut<'a, T: 'a> {
    data: &'a mut [T],
    shape: (usize, usize),
    idx_iter: Product<Range<usize>, Range<usize>>,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterator for Iter2DMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some((i, j)) = self.idx_iter.next() {
            Some(&mut self.data[i + self.shape.0 * j])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

and get the following error message.

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:13:23
   |
13 |             Some(&mut self.data[i + self.shape.0 * j])
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
```

Comment: Some more context here might help, to explain what exactly you are trying to do with this iterator. For instance, are you specifically needing to access the elements out of order in this way? Because if you can interchange the role of `i` and `j` then you would be iterating through the data in order, and this could be done efficiently with safe Rust.

Comment: I'm trying to iterate over 2d array but skip surrounding cells. For example, if x is a 2d array and its size is (m,n) , I'd like to iterate over x(3,3),x(4,3),x(5,3),...x(3,4),x(4,4),x(5,4)...x(m-4,n-3),x(m-3,n-3). I misunderstood the order of `Product` iterator. I should have written ` if let Some((j,i))=self.idx_iter_next(){`

Comment: In other words, you are trying to iterate over a rectangular subarray of the original array?

Comment: possible duplicate: [How can I create my own data structure with an iterator that returns mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730586/how-can-i-create-my-own-data-structure-with-an-iterator-that-returns-mutable-ref)

Answer (score 6):

Based on the author's clarification in the comments, I'm assuming that the goal here is to iterate over a rectangular submatrix of a matrix. For example, given a matrix

```
100  200  300  400  500  600
110  210  310  410  510  610
120  220  320  420  520  620
130  230  330  430  530  630
```

as represented by a slice in row-major order

```
[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 110, ..., 530, 630]
```

we want to iterate over a submatrix such as

```
210  310  410  510
220  320  420  520
```

again in row-major order, so the elements we would get would be, in order,

```
210, 310, 410, 510, 220, 320, 420, 520
```

In this situation, it is possible to solve this problem relatively efficiently using safe Rust. The trick is to use the [split_at_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) method of the slice in the `data` field of `Iter2DMut`, in order to peel off one mutable reference at a time as needed. As the iteration proceeds, the `data` field is updated to a smaller and smaller slice, so that it no longer encompasses elements which have already been iterated over; this is necessary, because at any given iteration Rust would not allow us to produce a mutable reference to an element while also retaining a mutable slice containing that element. By updating the slice, we can ensure that it is always disjoint from the mutable references which have been produced by all previous calls to `next()`, satisfying the Rust borrow checker. Here is how this can be done:

```
use itertools::{Itertools, Product};
use std::ops::Range;
use std::mem;

struct Iter2DMut<'a, T: 'a> {
    data: &'a mut [T],
    full_shape: (usize, usize),
    sub_shape: (usize, usize),
    idx_iter: Product<Range<usize>, Range<usize>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iter2DMut<'a, T> {
    fn new(
        data: &'a mut [T],
        full_shape: (usize, usize),
        sub_shape: (usize, usize),
        offset: (usize, usize),
    ) -> Self {
        assert!(full_shape.0 * full_shape.1 == data.len());
        assert!(offset.0 + sub_shape.0 <= full_shape.0);
        assert!(offset.1 + sub_shape.1 <= full_shape.1);
        Iter2DMut {
            data: &mut data[offset.0 * full_shape.1 + offset.1 ..],
            full_shape,
            sub_shape,
            idx_iter: (0..sub_shape.0).cartesian_product(0..sub_shape.1)
        }
    }
}
```

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterator for Iter2DMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some((_, j)) = self.idx_iter.next() {
            let mut data: &'a mut [T] = &mut [];
            mem::swap(&mut self.data, &mut data);
            let (first, rest) = data.split_at_mut(1);
            data = rest;
            if j == self.sub_shape.1 - 1 {
                let n_skip = self.full_shape.1 - self.sub_shape.1;
                let (_, rest) = data.split_at_mut(n_skip);
                data = rest;
            }
            self.data = data;
            Some(&mut first[0])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

```
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<usize> = vec![
        100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600,
        110, 210, 310, 410, 510, 610,
        120, 220, 320, 420, 520, 620,
        130, 230, 330, 430, 530, 630,
    ];
    for x in Iter2DMut::new(&mut v, (4, 6), (2, 4), (1, 1)) {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

There's one other trick here worth noting: we use `mem::swap` to move out the `data` field from the `Iter2DMut` in order to call `split_at_mut` on it. We temporarily swap in a dummy value `&mut []`; this is necessary since Rust won't allow us to move a value out of a (mutably) borrowed struct (even temporarily) without putting something back in at the same time. On the other hand, if we hadn't tried to move `data` out but had simply called `split_at_mut` directly, as in `self.data.split_at_mut(1)`, it would have failed the borrow checker, because then we would have been borrowing `self.data` which only lives as long as the the `&mut self` reference input into the `next` method, which is not necessarily long as the `'a` lifetime that we need it to be.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** This is a more general explanation of the problem of creating an iterator over mutable references. [Brent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62369356/493729) shows how to use a function from `std` to take care of the unsafe pointer manipulation for you, to solve this specific problem.

---

Iterating over mutable references requires unsafe code *somewhere*. To see why, consider a simpler example:

```
struct MyIterMut<'a, T: 'a> {
    data: &'a mut [T],
    index: usize,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterator for MyIterMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    let a;
    let b;
    {
        let mut iter = MyIterMut { data: &mut data, index: 0 };
        a = iter.next();
        b = iter.next();
    }

    // a and b  are usable after the iterator is dropped, as long as data is still around
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", a, b);
}
```

A user of this iterator is allowed to use values from the iterator after it is dropped, as long as the original data is still live. This is expressed in the type of `next` which, with explicit lifetimes added, is:

```
fn next<'n>(&'n mut self) -> Option<&'a mut T>
```

There is no relationship between `'n` and `'a`, so the code that uses the iterator is free to use them without constraint. This is what you want.

Suppose we implement `next()` like this:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut T> {
    Some(&mut self.data[0])
}
```

This implementation is Bad and causes the same error that you are seeing in your code. If the compiler allowed it, the `main` function above would have two variables, `a` and `b`, which both contain mutable references to the same data. This is Undefined Behaviour, and the borrow checker prevents it from happening.

The way it is prevented is by noting that you are borrowing from `self`, which has a lifetime that is unrelated to the lifetime of the data. The compiler has no way of knowing if `next` will be called multiple times or what the caller will do with the data. It only knows that there isn't enough information to decide if it's safe.

But, you may argue, you don't *need* to borrow the whole of `self`; you only need to borrow that single item from the slice. Unfortunately, when you borrow a piece of a struct, you borrow the entire struct. There is no way to express in the types that this call to `next()` will borrow index 0, and the next will borrow index 1 etc.

Given that you know that your implementation is only going to borrow each index once, you can use raw pointers and just tell the borrow-checker that you know what you  are doing:

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> Iterator for MyIterMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index < self.data.len() {
            let index = self.index;
            self.index += 1;
            let ptr = self.data.as_mut_ptr();
            Some(unsafe { &mut *ptr.add(index) })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Since the iterator takes a `&mut` reference to `data`, it is not possible to construct multiple instances of it. If it were possible then there would still be a possibility of Undefined Behaviour, but the Rust borrow-checker takes care of this for us.

---

Whenever using unsafe code, you need to be extremely careful of how you enforce any invariants that you have assumed.

In your case, you will also need to ensure that it is not possible to create an invalid pointer due to the `shape` not matching the size of the data. You should probably `panic!` if that happens, which is always preferable to Undefined Behaviour.

I hope the length of this answer communicates that you shouldn't go into this lightly. Always prefer to use safe functions from `std` or popular third party crates if they are available; your unsafe code will not receive the same level of peer review and testing that the Rust standard library gets.

Comment: I believe that in this specific situation, it is possible to solve the problem using safe Rust, by using `split_at_mut` to peel off the mutable references one at a time (see my answer), although this does come at the cost of some unnecessary bounds checks which could be eliminated using unsafe code. This takes advantage of the fact that for this given problem, we are basically iterating the elements in their contiguous order (but skipping some); if a more elaborate iteration order were required, then it would be pretty awkward to do without unsafe code.

Comment: @BrentKerby Good answer. Mine takes a more general approach and attempts to explain the fundamental issues of iterating over mutable references. Yours is probably the right answer to OP's specific problem.