# Why doesn't Rust let you use the innermost lifetime of nested mutable references?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have encountered a certain behavior of the borrow checker that I find rather odd: if I have a `&'a mut &'b mut T` where `'b: 'a, T: 'b`, it seems as though I should be able to treat it as just a `&'b mut T`, since I can guarantee that I have mutable access to the `T` for at least as long as `'b`. So, in its simplest form, (I think) I should be able to make a function such as this:

```rust
fn f<'a, 'b: 'a, T: 'b>(x: &'a mut &'b mut T) -> &'b mut T {
  *x
}
```

However, the borrow checker doesn't like that, saying

```rust
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
5 | fn f<'a, 'b: 'a, T: 'b>(x: &'a mut &'b mut T) -> &'b mut T {
  |                            -----------------
  |                            |
  |                            these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
6 |     *x
  |     ^^ ...but data from `x` flows into `x` here
```

My primary question is, why?

My secondary question is, are there safe ways to work around this?
I'm aware that I can cast it to a pointer and then turn it back into a reference, magically summoning whatever lifetime I want in the process, but that requires `unsafe` code. I would like to know if there are safe ways to do this, either in general or for specific circumstances (including circumstances in which specific `unsafe` code can be verified by the programmer to be safe).

As an example, my actual use case is an iterator that returns mutable references like `std::slice::IterMut<'a, T>` and that family of iterators; I have something along the lines of

```rust
struct IterMut<'a, T> {

  source: &'a mut MyContainer<T>,
  ... /* other data for iterating */

}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T> {

  type Item = &'a mut T;

  fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut T> {
    ...
  }

}
```

The problem is that inside the `next` method, I can only access the `source` reference through the `&mut self`, effectively creating a `&mut &'a MyContainer<T>`, which restricts my ability to borrow from `source` to the anonymous lifetime from `&mut self`, a la this question.

So in summary, why is this like this, and what steps can I take to avoid this problem?

Comment: `'b: 'a` means that `'b` is at least as long as `'a`; i.e. `'a` may end before `'b`. [see e.g. here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/lifetime_coercion.html). your function signature would work if you returned `&'a mut T` (i.e. the shorter lifetime, where `x` is guaranteed to be valid).

Comment: What you want is unsound, it could be used to get multiple mutable references to the same object. [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eedd88a1a33dc2e8dade8b4c9bd18342)

Comment: Since you bring up iterators, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730586/how-can-i-create-my-own-data-structure-with-an-iterator-that-returns-mutable-ref) may answer your question.

Comment: @kmdreko Ah, yes this makes sense now, thanks. If you make those into an answer I'll accept it.