# Conflicting Lifetimes - Burrowed Content is Unable to Outlive Container

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I'm trying to implement `Iterator` for one of my structs:

```
pub struct Node {
    pub val: Vec<usize>,
}

pub struct NodeIter<'a, 'b> {
    val: &'a Vec<usize>,
    env: &'b mut Env,

    index: usize,
}

impl<'a, 'b> Iterator for NodeIter<'a, 'b> {
    type Item = &'b mut Obj;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index < self.val.len() {
            return Some(self.env.get_obj_at_mut(self.val[self.index]))
        }

        self.index += 1;

        None
    }
}
```

and upon compilation get the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src\core\nodes.rs:20:23
   |
20 |         Some(self.env.get_obj_at_mut(self.val[self.index]))
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src\core\nodes.rs:19:13
   |
19 |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut Obj> {
   |             ^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src\core\nodes.rs:20:14
   |
20 |         Some(self.env.get_obj_at_mut(self.val[self.index]))
   |              ^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src\core\nodes.rs:16:6
   |
16 | impl<'a> Iterator for NodeIter<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src\core\nodes.rs:20:9
   |
20 |         Some(self.env.get_obj_at_mut(self.val[self.index]))
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Option<&'a mut Obj>`
              found `Option<&mut Obj>`
```

I understood the issue to be that the `&mut Obj` from `get_obj_at_mut` (which returns a &mut Obj with a lifetime of `'b`, same as `env`) might outlive `&mut self` leaving a null reference in its place. The issue is that `env` is bound by a mutable reference and may last beyond `NodeIter`

So I tried two options:

1. `'b: 'c`:

```
impl<'a, 'b> NodeIter<'a, 'b> {
    fn next_impl<'c>(&'c mut self) -> Option<&'b mut Obj> where 'b: 'c {
        if self.index < self.val.len() {
            return Some(self.env.get_obj_at_mut(self.val[self.index]))
        }

        self.index += 1;

        None
    }
}
```

this fails, stating that `'b` cannot outlive `'c`

2. `'c: 'b`

```
impl<'a, 'b> NodeIter<'a, 'b> {
    fn next_impl<'c>(&'c mut self) -> Option<&'b mut Obj> where 'c: 'b {
        if self.index < self.val.len() {
            return Some(self.env.get_obj_at_mut(self.val[self.index]))
        }

        self.index += 1;

        None
    }
}
```

this allowed `next-impl` to successfully compile, but it cannot be called from `next` due to the lifetime limitations

I know this might be similar to other questions about Rust lifetimes, but I haven't been able to figure out why `'b` can't outlive `'c` and more generally how to implement `Iterator`

I'm still new to Rust, so any help would be much appreciated

**EDIT**

```
pub fn get_obj_at_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Obj {
        &mut self.symbols[index]
}
```

this is in the `impl` block for `Env`, where `symbols` is an owned `Vec` of `Obj`

Comment: What is the code for `get_obj_at_mut()`?

Comment: It just retrieves an &mut Obj by index from a vec in env, I added the code at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted implementation would make it possible to hold two mutable borrows to the same `Obj` value if `val` contains a duplicate index.  Consider what would happen if `val` contained a duplicate index and the user of this code `.collect()`ed the iterator into a `Vec`!  That situation is not allowed by Rust's memory safety rules, and that's ultimately why the `next()` implementation fails to compile.

In fact, *any* implementation you could come up with is going to trip on that fundamental problem: nothing prevents `Iterator::next()` from being invoked again while you still hold a mutable reference returned from a prior call, and the language can't guarantee that all the mutable references produced by the iterator will alias different values.

So how do things like `iter_mut()` on slices work?  Easy: [they use unsafe code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25748645/501250).  `unsafe` is where you tell the compiler that you have done the work yourself to prove that what you're doing doesn't violate any of Rust's safety rules, and so it lets you do some extra things that you can't normally do.

If you want to do this without using unsafe code, you are going to have to swap the iteration around so that you call `iter_mut()` on whatever collection is internal to your `Env` and filter it down based on the indices in a `Node`.  This obviously has performance implications, and it also is very likely to iterate in a different order.

Here is a complete example showing how that can work, with placeholder methods for `Env`:

```
pub struct Env;
pub struct Obj;

impl Env {
    #[allow(unreachable_code)]
    pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&mut Obj> {
        todo!();
        
        std::iter::empty()
    }

    pub fn get_obj_at_mut(&mut self, _: usize) -> &mut Obj {
        todo!();
    }
}

pub struct Node {
    pub val: Vec<usize>,
}

impl Node {
    pub fn iter_mut<'a>(&'a self, env: &'a mut Env)
        -> impl Iterator<Item=&'a mut Obj>
    {
        env.iter_mut()
            .enumerate()
            .filter_map(move |(index, v)|
                if self.val.contains(&index) { Some(v) } else { None }
            )
    }
}
```

If the performance and ordering implications of this approach aren't acceptable, then unsafe code is your only resort.  In particular, **you must verify that `val` contains no duplicate indices** or you will violate Rust's rule that there must be at most one usable mutable reference to any given value.

If you have verified this before you construct the `NodeIter` value then you can use unsafe code to convince Rust that what you're doing here is okay.  Note that in this code I've also fixed the bug where the index is never incremented, because you return early.

```
impl<'a, 'b> Iterator for NodeIter<'a, 'b> {
    type Item = &'b mut Obj;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index < self.val.len() {
            let obj = self.env.get_obj_at_mut(self.val[self.index]);
            self.index += 1;

            // SAFETY: We already verified that self.val contains
            // no duplicate indices, and nobody can modify it while
            // we hold a reference to it, so it's not possible for
            // this iterator to produce two references to the same
            // value.

            // Convert to a pointer then back, which makes Rust
            // blind to the lifetime of the original reference.
            Some(unsafe { &mut *(obj as *mut _) })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer (and the increment bug, bound to have caused a problem if I ever were to get this working)