# Trying To Understand Generic Lifetime Parameters

Tags: rust

I got stuck while trying to implementing an `Iter` and `IterMut` for my container using only safe rust (the `std` use unsafe rust). After extracting the important parts, I got this code below.

```rust
struct Iter<'a>(&'a i32);

impl<'a> Iter<'a> {
    fn get<'b>(self: &'b Iter<'a>) -> &'a i32 {
        self.0
    }
}
```

and:

```rust
struct IterMut<'a>(&'a mut i32);

impl<'a> IterMut<'a> {
    fn get<'b>(self: &'b IterMut<'a>) -> &'a i32 {
        self.0
    }
}
```

and the error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:13:9
   |
11 | impl<'a> IterMut<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
12 |     fn get<'b>(self: &'b IterMut<'a>) -> &'a i32 {
   |            -- lifetime `'b` defined here
13 |         self.0
   |         ^^^^^^ associated function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'b`
   |
   = help: consider adding the following bound: `'b: 'a`
```

My question is **how** does the compiler know the impl of `Iter` work but not the `IterMut`? Does it have anything to do with variance?

I understand why it **should** work for `Iter` and not for `IterMut`, but not **why**. It should work because the `get` method return a reference of lifetime `'a` which might not coincide with lifetime `'b` of the iter object. For `Iter` this is fine, we just have two immutable reference to `i32` (the iter and the return of `get`). But for `IterMut` we would have a mutable reference (the iter) and an immutable reference (the return of get) to `i32`, which is a no no.

For the error part, the compiler suggests making the return reference borrow the iter (ie. make its lifetime lives at most the lifetime of the iter). That is why it suggests `'b: 'a`.

Comment: @kmdreko Yup, this confirmed my reasoning. Thank you. Although, I wonder if there are any resources on how the compiler can deduce this.

Comment: Answered from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730586/how-can-i-create-my-own-data-structure-with-an-iterator-that-returns-mutable-ref