# Return a moving window of elements resulting from an iterator of Vec<u8>

Tags: iterator, rust

I'm trying to figure out how to return a window of elements from a vector that I've first filtered without copying it to a new vector.

So this is the naive approach which works fine but I **think** will end up allocating a new vector from line 5 which I don't really want to do.

```
let mut buf  = Vec::new();
file.read_to_end(&mut buf);
// Do some filtering of the read file and create a new vector for subsequent processing
let iter = buf.iter().filter(|&x| *x != 10 && *x != 13);
let clean_buf = Vec::from_iter(iter);
for iter in clean_buf.windows(13) {
    print!("{}",iter.len());
}
```

Alternative approach where I could use a chain()? to achieve the same thing without copying into a new Vec

```
for iter in buf.iter().filter(|&x| *x != 10 && *x != 13) {
    let window =  ???       
}
```

Comment: It is unclear from the description: do you need `buf` for anything else afterwards? Or can it be modified (after `read_to_end`)?

Comment: Once I have `clean_buf`, no I don't need it any further in this example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Vec::retain`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) instead of `filter` for this, which allows you to keep your Vec:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut buf = vec![
        8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    ];
    println!("{:?}", buf);
    buf.retain(|&x| x != 10 && x != 13);
    println!("{:?}", buf);
    for iter in buf.windows(13) {
        print!("{}, ", iter.len());
    }
    println!("");
}
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought the OP would allow modifying the buffer in place! Nice lateral thinking :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this would be possible. You say:

> elements from a vector that I've first filtered

But once you've `filter`ed a vector, you don't have a vector anymore - you just have an `Iterator`. `Iterator`s only have the concept of the next item.

To be most efficient, you'd have to create a small buffer of the size of your window. Unfortunately, you [cannot write an iterator that returns a reference to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25702909/155423), so you'd have to pass in a buffer to a hypothetical `Iterator::windows` method. In that case, you'd run into the problem of having a mutable reference (so you could populate the buffer) and an immutable reference (so you could return a slice), which won't fly.

The only close solution I can think of is to have multiple iterators over the same vector that you then `zip` together:

```
fn main() {
    let nums: Vec<u8> = (1..100).collect();

    fn is_even(x: &&u8) -> bool { **x % 2 == 0 }

    let a = nums.iter().filter(is_even);
    let b = nums.iter().filter(is_even).skip(1);
    let c = nums.iter().filter(is_even).skip(2);

    for z in a.zip(b).zip(c).map(|((a, b), c)| (a,b,c)) {
        println!("{:?}", z);
    }  
}
```

This has the distinct downside of needing to apply the filtering condition multiple times, and the ugliness of the nested zips (you can fix the latter with use of [itertools](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/macro.izip!.html) though).

Personally, I'd probably just `collect` into a `Vec`, as you have already done.