# Issues constraining implementation lifetimes on type without lifetime parameter

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to implement a BST in Rust (for HW3 in [this](http://cis198-2016s.github.io/schedule/) lovely intro to Rust), and I'm running into errors with lifetimes, and how to constrain lifetimes for types that are related to types without a lifetime.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct BST<T>
    where T: Ord
{
    root: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

// A couple dozen lines of BST stuff

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for BST<T>
    where T: Ord
{
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = BSTIter<'a, T>; // <- my intuition is that I should
                                        // be able to say "BSTIter lives as
                                        // long as BST."

    fn into_iter(&'a mut self) -> BSTIter<'a, T> {
        BSTIter::new(&mut self)
    }
}


pub struct BSTIter<'a, T: 'a>
    where T: Ord + 'a
{
    bst: &'a mut BST<T>,
    node_list: Vec<&'a Node<T>>, // this is where the need for a lifetime on
                                 // BSTIter comes from
}


impl<'a, T> BSTIter<'a, T>
    where T: Ord
{
    fn new(&mut bst: BST<T>) -> BSTIter<'a, T> {
        let traverse_stack = Vec::new();
        if let Some(ref x) = bst.root {
            traverse_stack.push(x);
        }
        BSTIter {
            bst: bst,
            node_list: traverse_stack,
        }
    }
}


impl<'a, T> Iterator for BSTIter<'a, T>
    where T: Ord
{
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        // BST iteration details
    }
}
```

As it stands, this code spits out the error

```
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
   --> src/lib.rs:117:7
    |
117 | impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for BST <T> where T: Ord {
    |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter
```

If the `IntoIterator` trait didn't require me to specify `type IntoIterator = BSTIter`, the implementation block could just have an `into_iter` method signature of `into_iter<'a>(&'a mut self) -> BSTIter<'a, T>`. Since I need to specify the lifetime for `BSTIter`, it seems like I need to specify a lifetime for the entire BST type. Again, my instinct says that I shouldn't have to specify a lifetime on BST to be able to create an iterator for it.

I realize the two solutions to this are likely one (or both) of

1. There's a language feature that helps me get around this
2. Somewhere along the way, my code became very much not idiomatic Rust

If I could get help on either how to make the above code snippet work, or how I should be approaching these lifetime and ownership details in general, it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: This code does not provide a [MCVE]. Notably absent is the **entire `BSTIntoIter` struct**! It's unclear why your consuming iterator has a lifetime at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've misunderstood the purpose and usage of `IntoIterator`. It converts a value *into* an iterator; **consuming the value** in the process. However, your iterator is attempting to return references to the collection. [You cannot return references into the iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25702909/155423), so it makes no sense to consume the tree, transferring ownership to the iterator.

The fact that you've called it `BSTIter` instead of `BSTIntoIter` shows promise; as that's the idiomatic name for an iterator that returns references.

You want to implement `IntoIterator` for `&'a BST<T>`, not `BST<T>`. You could *also* implement it for `BST<T>`, but then you'd want to yield `T`, not `&T`.

After fixing that, there's lots of compiler errors: mismatched types all throughout the code, incorrect method signatures in traits (`fn into_iter(self)` is all you are allowed), for some reason there's a mutable reference to the tree, variables aren't mutable when they should be....

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T>(Option<Box<T>>);

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct BST<T>
    where T: Ord
{
    root: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a BST<T>
    where T: Ord
{
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = BSTIter<'a, T>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> BSTIter<'a, T> {
        BSTIter::new(self)
    }
}

pub struct BSTIter<'a, T: 'a>
    where T: Ord + 'a
{
    bst: &'a BST<T>,
    node_list: Vec<&'a Node<T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> BSTIter<'a, T>
    where T: Ord
{
    fn new(bst: &'a BST<T>) -> BSTIter<'a, T> {
        let mut traverse_stack = Vec::new();
        if let Some(ref x) = bst.root {
            traverse_stack.push(&**x);
        }
        BSTIter {
            bst: bst,
            node_list: traverse_stack,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for BSTIter<'a, T>
    where T: Ord
{
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        None
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! It solves my problem (being that I was approaching it from the wrong angle), so I'm going to mark it as accepted.