# How do I write a generic iterator that keeps a state and returns a value without using clone?

Tags: generics, rust, iterator, clone

I tried to write a generic iterator, but I do not see how to return value without using `clone`. Is there any way to create a variable within the `next` function and return a reference? If I replace `T` with `u32`, then I can just return `Some(self.count)`, but using generics, it is not possible.

```
use num_traits::Num;
use std::clone::Clone;

struct Counter<T>
where
    T: Num + Clone,
{
    count: T,
}

impl<T> Counter<T>
where
    T: Num + Clone,
{
    fn new() -> Counter<T> {
        Counter { count: T::zero() }
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for Counter<T>
where
    T: Num + Clone,
{
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.count = self.count.clone() + T::one();
        Some(self.count.clone())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut number: Counter<u32> = Counter::new();

    match number.next() {
        Some(x) => println!("Number {}", x),
        None => println!("Invalid"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the one hand... no, you cannot make the iterator return a reference to the counter's value. The `Iterator::next()` method returns a value which has no lifetime connection with the receiver value `&mut self`, so we cannot control the lifetime of the reference that would be returned there. This would be required because we cannot modify the value while it's borrowed by that reference. This concern is better explained in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25702909/1233251).

*On the other hand*, the real concern emerges here:

> If I replace `T` with `u32`, then I can just return `Some(self.count)`, but using generics, it is not possible.

This is only the case because `u32` implements `Copy`, which means that it is copied around whenever it is necessary. Types implementing `Copy` also implement `Clone`, which would do just about the same thing as a copy, which would have happened in the non-generic context.

As such, the cloning operations that you have in this are reasonable, since you want to return the value of the counter while still owning its own state. When the `T` of that counter is a primitive integer such as `u32`, the clone is as cheap as a copy of that integer.

Other than that, you can add a constraint for `T` on `AddAssign<T>`, so that you can use the `+=` operator to increment the internal state.

```rust
impl<T> Iterator for Counter<T> where T: Num + Clone + AddAssign<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.count += T::one();
        Some(self.count.clone())
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Can I write an Iterator that mutates itself and then yields a reference into itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25702909/1233251)
- [What is the difference between Copy and Clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31012923/1233251)
- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/1233251)

Comment: Another option is to require `T: Copy` instead of `T: Clone`, which will allow to use `Some(self.count)` as the return value. There isn't really any advantage to doing so – it will only make the code less generic by further restricting `T` – but it illustrates the parallel to the `u32` case.